# How to enable restore a softdeleted item on in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have created a CRUD module with `softdelete` option, but now I need to add the `restore` option to the list table

I'm using `backpackforlaravel` with **laravel** 8 for the admin side.

from **backpackforlaravel Docs:**
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs I actived the **softdelete**:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\CrudController;

class ProductCrudController extends CrudController
{
    use \Backpack\CRUD\app\Http\Controllers\Operations\DeleteOperation;
}
```

I found this **filter to show the deleted** items on the list:

```
$this->crud->addFilter([
  'type'  => 'simple',
  'name'  => 'trashed',
  'label' => 'Trashed'
],
false,
function($values) { // if the filter is active
    $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->onlyTrashed();
});
```

#### Now, How to restore items?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#restoring-soft-deleted-models

Comment: good, that's helpful, I will try it but  if someone provides me with more details I will be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solved,

If you are using `backpackforlaravel` apply the next steps to add **restore soft-deleted items**.

**Step1: On the `Model` add this function:**

*This function will return the button.*

```
    public function restoreActionButton()
    {
        return '<a href="' . url("/admin/product/restore/{$this->id}") . '" class="btn btn-sm btn-link" data-button-type="delete"><i class="la la-trash-restore"></i> Restore </a>';
    }
```

**Step2: add the `route` to the controller function:**

*This route must match the one returned from the model.*

```
    Route::get(
        '/admin/product/restore/{id}',
        [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ProductCrudController::class, 'restore']
    );
```

**Step3: now the restore function, add it to the `controller`.**

```
    public function restore($id)
    {
        Product::withTrashed()->find($id)->restore();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

above the class

```
use App\Models\Product;
```

**Step4: (Optional) update the filter on the same `controller`:**

*This will hide all buttons when the user applies the deleted filter.*

```
       $this->crud->addFilter(
            [
                'type'  => 'simple',
                'name'  => 'trashed',
                'label' => 'Trashed'
            ],
            false,
            function ($values) { // if the filter is active
                // $this->crud->addClause('trashed');
                $this->crud->query = $this->crud->query->onlyTrashed();
                $this->crud->removeAllButtonsFromStack('line');
                $this->crud->addButtonFromModelFunction('line', 'restore', 'restoreActionButton');
            }
        );
```